# Estimed number of tries

Tags: c++, algorithms, problem-solving

**Problem:**

The Oscar Committee wants to decide which person should get the best actor award among the given N actors.For that they decided to use a random function random_bit() which returns either 0 or 1 with equal probablity. For the results to be fair,the committee was asked to generate a random number between 1 to N (inclusive) , such that all
actors have equal probability of being chosen (which in this case should always be equal to 1 / N.

First of all Committee wants to know the expected number of times they will need to call random_bit() function to generate a random number between 1 to N.Also, while calling the function, they should follow the optimal strategy (i.e. the strategy that minimizes the expected number of function calls)

---

This is problem of  past contests at codechef.com and here's the [link](http://www.codechef.com/BTBT2014/problems/COG14C) to it.

This site allows to see other users solution and till now only one solution has been accepted. The solution is in C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std
int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    for(int ii = 0; ii<T; ++ii) 
    {
         int N;
         cin >> N;
         double p = 1, ans = 0;
         int x = 1 % N;
         for(int i = 0; i<100000; ++i)
         {
              ans += x * p;
              x = (x * 2) % N;
              p /= 2;
         }
         cout << ans;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know how the code runs and what it does, but I can't find the logic behind it. Any help/ clue?

Also it would be nice if someone can post another algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the code interprets the string of random bits as a binary fraction, converts this to a N-ary fraction, and looks at the first digit of that N-ary fraction to determine the winner.

The question then becomes: *How many random bits do we need until the first digit of the N-ary fraction is stable?*

For all examples, I'll use N=3. The 3-ary fraction will start with

- a 0 when the fraction is between 0 and 0.333333
- a 1 when between 0.333333 and 0.666667
- a 2 when between 0.666667 and 1.000000

E.g. 0.11... (binary) = at least 0.75... (decimal) = 0.2.. (3-ary) as it lays between 0.666667 and 1.

In this case, we could stop after 2 bits of input. However, in some cases, we can't decide yet because the number is still too close to a boundary.

E.g. 0.01.... (binary) = between 0.25 and 0.5, so could be 0.0... (3-ary) or 0.1... (3-ary). So we need to look at more bits:

- If that next bit is 1: 0.011... (binary) = between 0.375 and 0.5, so will always start with 0.1... (3-ary).
- If that next bit is zero: 0.010... (binary) = between 0.25 and 0.375, so still we can't decide whether it is 0.0... (3-ary) or 0.1... (3-ary). So we ask for another bit.

So we always need at least two bits, sometimes a third, in even less cases a fourth, and so on.

Apparently but I'm not sure,  `x*p` tracks the chance for needing yet-another-bit. `ans` is the sum of those chances. I can't fully explain this part of the algorithm, maybe somebody else can?

`x*p` gets smaller over time. At first it is stable, as each iteration p gets halved and x gets doubled. But sometimes x is reduced by the `% N` part. At some point, the current value of `ans` will dwarf `x*p` and the answer is as close as you can get. (However, 100000 iterations seems an awful lot. See below)

I hope this helps to understand what's going on.

---

Some additional observations about the code:

- Once `x` becomes equal to zero, it will stay zero, and `ans` will not change anymore. The for loop could break at that point. This only happens when N is a power of 2, so is pretty rare (e.g. for N=3, x cycles through 1, 2, and back to 4=1).
- 100000 looks like a insanely high upper limit. `p` is a double and starts at 1.0, so can be halved at most 1024 times before becoming denormalized. 53 halvations later, `p` will be so small that it will be rounded to zero.
- Even stronger: as x and p both start at 1, `ans` will be set to 1 during the first iteration. At some point, `x*p` will become less than 2^-53, and when added to `ans` will be too small to matter and will be ignored due to rounding. As p will be halved each iteration, this will take between 53 and, say, 100 iterations max, depending on N.

Comment: Nice explanation of the method it uses, I was almost certain that it uses "binary search" method, but I thought of it like breaking the set into two halves and randomly choosing one, but I had problems when we had odd number of elements in the set.

Anyway, thanks for the explanation, but can explan what x doubles over time (Why not let say triples)? And why we eventualy reduce it by %N part? I understand why p halves, but can't get over why x doubles

Comment: Actually can you explain how does iteration on x*p gives us the answer?

Comment: @Stefan4024 `x = (x*2) % N` doubles x in every iteration, until it becomes greater than N. E.g. for N=13, x will be 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 10, 7, 1. Especially at the start, the doubling is clearly visible.

Comment: @Stefan4024 I don't understand why `ans += x * p;` yields the correct answer. Apparently it does, as you said it was accepted as answer. I can explain why p halves: for each bit sequence that isn't clear yet, the next bit will make it clear in half of the cases, and postpones it in the other half. But I don't understand the formula for x. I would have expected something like `ans += (N-1)*p` for odd N, as there are N-1 undetermined bit sequences at any point (for powers of 2, there will be less such sequences), but I don't see how `x*p` adds up to N-1. My intuition fails me here.